# Send back an HTTP Response without receiving a Request

Tags: c#, http

I have a C# server that will accept connections from a game/client and return information from a database to the game/client.

The client posts an xml file. I would like to send a `200 OK` Response back to the client.

I have tried numerous things. Can anyone suggest something. I also need the response to `HTTP 1.0`.

Thanks.

Comment: You tried numerous things. Can you share those with us? That might clarify and prevent some people reinventing your wheel, which is not helpfull to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting response status code manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678433/setting-response-status-code-manually)

Comment: I tried using the Http Response class and the HttpWebResponse class as well. However, the outputstream seems to a text writer. I just want it to stream back across the network. I want to do something similar to Java's BasicHttpResponse. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to write an application that serves web requests with responses and want it to be (relatively) lightweight, at least in regards to IIS, try looking into the [Kayak Project](https://github.com/kayak/kayak). Seems pretty close to what you're aiming to do.

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/kayak-http/browse_thread/thread/b9d6742f3f646812) in the mailing list seems especially relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is so confusing... "send back" without request in the title... but a request is done when you explain later the full problem...

Anyway, I don't know if this is what you want to do, but can send your own headers using the Status and StatusCode properties of the HttpResponse class.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion  but i wanted to do something similar to Java's BasicHttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_0, HttpStatus.SC_OK, "OK");
iOut.write(response.toString().concat(CRLF + CRLF).getBytes());

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't really understand the http response. I forgot to send back the two CRLF at the end of the response. Thanks alot.

```
--definitions:   CRLF = "\r\n"; s = NetworkStream().


StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.Append("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
str.Append("Date: Tue, 17 Aug 2011 11:40:00 EST\r\n");
str.Append("Server: Apache\r\n");
str.Append("Content-Type: text/xml\r\n");
str.Append("Content Length: 128\r\n");

byte [] r = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str.ToString() + CRLF+ CRLF);
s.Write(r, 0, r.Length);
```