# Conditionally setting the HTTP status without directly manipulating the HttpServletResponse

Tags: http, spring-mvc, http-status-codes

How can I conveniently conditionally set the HTTP status code in an Spring MVC request handler?

I have a request handler that responds to POST requests, for creation of a new resource. If the request is valid I want it to redirect to the URI of the new resource, returning a 201 (Created) HTTP status code. If the request is invalid I want it to give the user a chance to correct the error in the submitted form, and should not give a status code of 201.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/myURI/" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String processNewThingForm(
    @ModelAttribute(value = "name") final String name,
    final BindingResult bindingResult) {

  myValidator.validate(name, bindingResult);

  if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
     getService().createThing(name);
     return "redirect:" + name;
  } else {
     return "newThingView";
  }
```

}

But that does not give the correct response status for the redirection case.

I can't simply add a `@ResponseStatus`, because there are two possible statuses. I'm hoping there is a neater way than [manually manipulating the `HttpServletResponse`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678433/setting-response-status-code-manually?). And I want to indicate the view name to use, so I can not [have the request handler return a `ResponseEntity` object with the status set appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16250729/545127).

Answer (score 3):

In case you want a 201 response code, you can return a [ResponseEntity](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) with [HttpStatus.CREATED](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html) when the resource is created and the view name otherwise. If so, you cannot use a redirect (http code 301). See [RedirectView](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html).

Comment: "If so, you cannot use a redirect" I know. That is the point of my question