# Dynamically changing the @ResponseStatus in annotation driven Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I am really not sure if this is feasible using Spring 3.2 MVC.

My Controller has a method declared as below:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody List<Foo> getAll(){
    return service.getAll();
}
```

**Questions:**

1. What is the meaning of `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)` ?
2. Does it signifies that the method will always return a `HttpStatus.OK` status code.
3. What if an exception is thrown from the service layer?
4. Can I change the Response Status on occurrence of any exception?
5. How can I handle multiple response statuses depending on conditions in the same method?

Comment: **1.** Please read [Status](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) Probably you should use `ResponseEntity`.

Comment: http://www.captaindebug.com/2012/02/spring-3-mvc-exception-handlers-and_14.html#.Vapp2JSgPqR

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)` means that the request will return OK if the handling method returns normally (this annotation is redundant for this case, as the default response status is `HttpStatus.OK`). If the method throws an exception, the annotation does not apply; instead, the status will be determined by Spring using an exception handler.

> How can I handle multiple response statuses depending on conditions in the same method?

That question [has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238057/conditionally-setting-the-http-status).

> Can I change the Response Status on occurrence of any exception

You have two choices. If the exception class is one of your own, you could annotate the exception class with `@ResponseStatus`. The other choice is to provide the controller class with an exception handler, annotated with `@ExceptionHandler`, and have the exception handler set the response status.

Comment: >If the handler throws an exception, the annotation does not apply.

what does this mean? What would be the response in that case?

Answer (score 13):

If you return a ResponseEntity directly, you can set the HttpStatus in that:

```
// return with no body or headers    
return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

If you want to return an error other than 404, [HttpStatus has lots of other values](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html) to choose from.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot set multiple status value for `@ResponseStatus`. One approach I can think of is to use `@ExceptionHandler` for response status which is not `HttpStatus.OK`

```
@RequestMapping(value =  "login.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute Login login) {
    if(loginIsValidCondition) {
        //process login
        //.....
        return new ModelAndView(...);
    }
    else{
        throw new InvalidLoginException();
    }
}

@ExceptionHandler(InvalidLoginException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ModelAndView invalidLogin() {
    //handle invalid login  
    //.....
    return new ModelAndView(...);
}
```