# Spring: return @ResponseBody "ResponseEntity<List<JSONObject>>"

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, http-status-codes

In controller I create json array. If I return `List<JSONObject>` it is ok:

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<JSONObject> getAll() {
    List<Entity> entityList = entityManager.findAll();

    List<JSONObject> entities = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (Entity n : entityList) {
        JSONObject entity = new JSONObject();
        entity.put("id", n.getId());
        entity.put("address", n.getAddress());
        entities.add(entity);
    }
    return entities;
}
```

but I need to return JSON array and HTTP status code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<List<JSONObject>> getAll() {
    List<Entity> entityList = entityManager.findAll();

    List<JSONObject> entities = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (Entity n : entityList) {
        JSONObject Entity = new JSONObject();
        entity.put("id", n.getId());
        entity.put("address", n.getAddress());
        entities.add(entity);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(entities, HttpStatus.OK); // XXX
}
```

Eclipse see error in XXX line:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The constructor ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(List<JSONObject>, HttpStatus) is undefined
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from ResponseEntity<JSONObject> to 
     ResponseEntity<List<JSONObject>>
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from ResponseEntity<JSONObject> to JSONObject
```

How can I return json+http reply? There is my working code for returning one json object + http status code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{address}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<JSONObject> getEntity(@PathVariable("address") int address) {
    Entity n = entityManager.findByAddress(address);
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
    o.put("id", n.getId());
    o.put("address", n.getAddress());
    return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(o, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: I think it should've just been `return new ResponseEntity<List<JSONObject>>(entities, HttpStatus.OK);` right? Regardless, your solution below is fine.

Comment: Thanks, it works. What is better? `ResponseEntity<List<JSONObject>>` or `ResponseEntity<Object>` What is your opinion?

Comment: For readability concerns, the former is better in my opinion.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Now I return `Object`. I don't know better solution, but it works.

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Object> getAll() {
    List<Entity> entityList = entityManager.findAll();

    List<JSONObject> entities = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (Entity n : entityList) {
        JSONObject Entity = new JSONObject();
        entity.put("id", n.getId());
        entity.put("address", n.getAddress());
        entities.add(entity);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(entities, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Other solution is use http://stackoverflow.com/a/17539455/1974494 `@ResponseStatus` and `@ExceptionHandler`.

Comment: ResponseEntity<Object> works for an obvious reason, because Object is parent class for everything

Comment: I tried the same (return new ResponseEntity<Object>(entities, HttpStatus.OK);)but the controller returning empty array for me. Any suggestions please

Answer (score 35):

Instead of

```
return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(entities, HttpStatus.OK);
```

try

```
return new ResponseEntity<List<JSONObject>>(entities, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Answer (score 13):

Personally, I prefer changing the method signature to:

```
public ResponseEntity<?>
```

This gives the advantage of possibly returning an error message as single item for services which, when ok, return a list of items.

When returning I don't use any type (which is unused in this case anyway):

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(entities, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the other answers didn't work for me (error 500) but this works

```
@GetMapping("")
public String getAll() {
    List<Entity> entityList = entityManager.findAll();
    List<JSONObject> entities = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (Entity n : entityList) {
        JSONObject Entity = new JSONObject();
        entity.put("id", n.getId());
        entity.put("address", n.getAddress());
        entities.add(entity);
    }
    return entities.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I am late for this but i want put some more solution relevant to this.

```
 @GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<JSONObject>> getRole() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.getRole());
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reference to a service or role in the original question, and besides, how would you get each JSONObjects role without iterating through the list of JSONObjects?